# Trying to map a Date to object using mysqlconnector in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop, mysql-connector, data-access-layer

I am trying to read information from my DAL and am wondering what built in types am I suppose to use in C# to extract the `DATE` Data Type in MySql to retrieve information. Am I suppose to use DateTime and convert the DateTime to Date or is there a way in C# where we can retrieve specified information when calling upon it. I have an image of the DS at the bottom

`DATA_ACCESS_LAYER CODE SNIPIT`

```cs
using MySqlConnector;
...
...
private IObject ReadInformation(MySqlDataReader reader, IObject object)
{
    try 
    {
        while (reader.Read)
        {
            ((Object)object).Birthday = reader.getDateOnly("Birthday"); 
            // ^ My Current issue of questioning what Data type 
            // do I have to use under the reader and do I have to change the 
            // IObject.Birthday datatype.
        }
    }
    // catch code
}
```

`Object Interface`

```cs
class IObject 
{
    string FirstName;
    ...
    DateOnly Birthday;
}
```

`Object Class`

```cs
class Object : IObject
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    ... 
    public DateOnly Birthday { get; set; }
}
```

`Image of the MySQL Database Field`
[image]

Comment: The `Date` type (in C# land) is very new. Until recently, only `DateTime` was available for tracing Dates. As a result, all DB interfaces are still based on DateTime (as far as I know). Your guess is correct

Comment: *DON'T* use `Object` as a class name. `Object` is the base class from which all .NET types derive.

Comment: Which provider and version are you using? The open source MySqlConnector (not the official Connector/.NET that's full of bugs) [added support 11 months ago](https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector/blob/master/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlDataReader.cs#L265) even though it's just a `DateOnly.FromDateTime(GetDateTime(ordinal))` you could do yourself. Are you targeting .NET 6? Did you upgrade to the latest MySqlConnector version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```cs
class IObject
{
    string FirstName;
    ...
    DateTime Birthday; // Changed DateOnly to DateTime within the model 
}
```

The Answer was my initial assumption that I must change the datatype from DateOnly -> DateTime.  -- Answered by Flydog57

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You *can* use `DateOnly` [in MySqlConnector](https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector/blob/master/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlDataReader.cs#L265). That method simply uses `DateOnly.FromDateTime(GetDateTime(ordinal))`, which you could use in your own code